Encounter circular package dependency -- how to remove
I've encountered a circular dependency between plasma-workspace, xdg-desktop-portal-kde, and plasma-integration.
I want to remove these all; how should I go about that?

Remove them all in the same package manager command.  That's how I'd install a circular dependency, so it makes sense for removing one.
